# Is there a reverse Font lookup for copyrighted fonts?

Tags: fonts, copyright

I often get font files from other designers. Is there a way for me to check if those fonts are copyrighted and require me to have a license to use them.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on a **Mac**, you may be able to view licensing information in Font Book, and for **Windows**, open fonts settings in Control Panel. You can possibly try a font creation app, such as Glyphs or [Fontforge](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) to view license information.

Comment: I am a customer printer. I am having designers collect all the assets they use with there designs including the font files to save me the hassle of looking for the font.  I was thinking to have a script on our upload that automatically checks for the license on the font. My concern is that if I post a tshirt online for sale, and I get contacted about a font license, I can show that I have one. even if the designer did not pay for it. I assume that when I put a shirt up for sale the "for personal use" like they have on dafont, automatically changes over to commercial use.

Comment: @JMichael oh! Now I get what you are asking. If you know the font name, and it's a commercial font, MyFonts.com should list it (even if they don't sell it) 90% of the time. Granted, there are tons of 'free' fonts that do require a commercial license if you plan to sell a product that used it. Alas, I don't think there is any standard way to handle licenses nor any central repository of all fonts out there.

Answer (score 1):

What The Font is the most popular one:

https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

There are others.

FYI, if you're getting font files from other designers, unless the the license allows for re-distribution, they are likely breaking the license of the fonts. Technically, you should have your own license of the font if you are going to work on the files further on your own hardware.

Finally, you shouldn't have to be jumping through hoops to figure out fonts. If they are bundling the fonts, you should have the license right there with the font file. If not, you should be able to ask the designer "what fonts are these?" directly.

Comment: yeah, I was looking more for something like reverse image search to find and purchase a license. I would already know what the font is. I'm trying to streamline the process as much as possible using a Photoshop/illustrator script that grabs all of the assets. BUT I would still need to have my own licenses if I wanted to re sell the work I assume.

Comment: @JMichael What The Font is an image search tool. You upload an image of the font. Technically, you need a license for the font if you want to use the font on your computer. It doesn't have anything to do with reselling.